# Character Picture Grid exercise - automatetheboringstuff

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, formatting

Regarding the Character picture exercise located at the end the following page:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter4/

> Say you have a list of lists where each value in the inner lists is a
>   one-character string, like this:
>
> ```
> grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
>         ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
>         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
>         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
>         ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
>         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
>         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
>         ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
>         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
> ```
>
> You can think of `grid[x][y]` as being the character at the x- and
>   y-coordinates of a “picture” drawn with text characters. The `(0, 0)`
>   origin will be in the upper-left corner, the x-coordinates increase
>   going right, and the y-coordinates increase going down.
>
> Copy the previous grid value, and write code that uses it to print the
>   image.
>
> ```
> ..OO.OO..
> .OOOOOOO.
> .OOOOOOO.
> ..OOOOO..
> ...OOO...
> ....O....
> ```

I wrote the following code, any feedback is appreciated.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(6):
    for a in range(9):
        if a < 8:
            print(grid[a][i], end="")
        else:
            print(grid[a][i])
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code is pretty good. It's what I'd expect the author of the book to have wanted their readers to write.

Good job!

---

In terms of making the code more understandable/maintainable you can get the same functionality using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip), [`*args`](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), [`''.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a single `print`.

```
for column in zip(*grid):
    print(''.join(column))
```

Comment: That's actually pretty cool! I had to think a moment to see what's going on here. But it's really clever. Basically a matrix transpose in plain Python.

Comment: Now that is short. Thanks for the answer. I will have to take a look at those functions.

Answer (score 5):

As @Peilonrayz said - your code is well built and according to me, unexpectedly short which is certainly a good job as most people tend to write long programs for short tasks like this.

---

But you could make it much shorter (a single line perhaps) -

```
>>> print('\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*grid))))

..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

The [`zip`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/)`(*grid)` effectively transposes the matrix (flip it on the main diagonal), then each row is [`joined`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/) into one string, then the rows are joined with newlines so the whole thing can be printed at once.

Here's what `map()` in Python is -

> *The **`map()`** function returns a list of the results after applying the given
>   function to each item of a given iterable (list, tuple, etc.)*

<sup><sup>Source - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/</sup></sup>

***BUT***

***`map()`*** is a built-in function which focuses on functional programming. It may be useful for hacks and tricks since it shortens the code, but can be a bad idea for large projects in use.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Map's semi-depricated, defiantly discouraged. IIRC the Google code style also discourages it too.

Comment: @Peilonrayz - I used `map()` because of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map - for a more elegant solution. But I agree with your comment.