# Apply same format function to each python print() parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I have a python `print` statement and inside the string I wish to print are four digits. I would like to apply the same formatting function to each param. I am not familiar with the latest and greatest features of python PEPs.

#### Is there a slick way to do this?

### Code

```
statement = "Splitting up the {} file into {} chunks, with the filesystem block size of {}, causing {} extra space to be used"

print(statement.format(
    sizeof_fmt(input_file_size), 
    sizeof_fmt(chunk_size), 
    sizeof_fmt(block_size), 
    sizeof_fmt(surrendered_space)))
```

### Format Function

```
def sizeof_fmt(num, suffix='B'):
    for unit in ['','Ki','Mi','Gi','Ti','Pi','Ei','Zi']:
        if abs(num) < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f%s%s" % (num, unit, suffix)
        num /= 1024.0
    return "%.1f%s%s" % (num, 'Yi', suffix)
```

Comment: This is not really a code review type question, and would be better asked on StackOverflow.  But the slick way you are looking for is the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#map) function.

Comment: @AJNeufeld - I have been told something here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222292/character-picture-grid-exercise-automatetheboringstuff/222307#222307. Is it true?

Comment: @Justin Ah.  PEP 279 ... written in 2002, contains no mention of deprecating `map`, but a comment by GvR on the PEP suggested it should die.  A discussion in 2005 suggested it might be gone by Python 3.0 ... which was released in December 2008.  Now it is 11 years later, and I still see no signs of `map` being deprecated.  True: you can use list comprehension instead of map, and in some cases it might be faster and clearer, but in others it can be slower and/or less clear.  YMMV, but I don’t expect map will ever go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time will tell if your question is considered a worthy Code Review question, but till then I'ld like you to give a short review on your code nevertheless.

## Format function

You could reduce the code duplication in the format function and make use of `.format` or f-strings (from Python 3.6 onwards).

```py
def sizeof_fmt_rev(num, suffix='B'):
    for unit in ['', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Gi', 'Ti', 'Pi', 'Ei', 'Zi']:
        if abs(num) < 1024.0:
            break
        num /= 1024.0
    else:
        # this part is only executed if the loop was not left with a break
        unit = 'Yi'
    return f"{num:.1f}{unit}{suffix}"
```

This uses [`for ... else`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980160/5682996), one of the less well-known features of Python and only has a single line where the format expression has to be written. <strike>I see a chance to build something using [`math.log`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log) instead of that loop, but I will leave that as an exercise to you.</strike> You can even build something that works without a loop, but at least the version I came up with (found below) is actually slower than the original implementation.

```
def sizeof_fmt_rev_log(num, suffix='B'):
    exponent = min(int(math.log(abs(num), 1024)), 8)
    num /= 1024**exponent
    unit = ('', 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Gi', 'Ti', 'Pi', 'Ei', 'Zi', 'Yi')[exponent]
    return f"{num:.1f}{unit}{suffix}"
```

I used

```
for i in range(10):
    num = 3.8 * 1024**i
    print(sizeof_fmt_rev(num))
    assert sizeof_fmt(num) == sizeof_fmt_rev(num)
    assert sizeof_fmt(-num) == sizeof_fmt_rev(-num)
```

to test the revised version.

## Code

As [@AJNeufeld](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/100620/) mentions in his comment, you could use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to save yourself some typing

```py
print(
    statement.format(*map(sizeof_fmt, (input_file_size, chunk_size, block_size, surrendered_space)))
)
```

which is functionally equivalent to using a list comprehension:

```
print(
    statement.format(*[
        sizeof_fmt(i)
        for i in (input_file_size, chunk_size, block_size, surrendered_space)
    ])
)
```

Both build upon a technique called [tuple unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2238361/5682996), but as you can see it can also be used with lists, other sequences, and <strike>maybe</strike> also iterables (if it is a generator, it will be consumed - thanks [@Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98493/), who confirmed it/pointed it out in a [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222472/apply-same-format-function-to-each-python-print-parameter/222486?noredirect=1#comment430937_222486)).

Comment: Tuple unpacking can indeed be used with any iterable. It will be consumed by it if it is a generator.