# Automate The Boring Stuff - Character Picture Grid

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I understand there is [another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222292/character-picture-grid-exercise-automatetheboringstuff) on this already, however this is what I coded and wanted to know if this would raise any red flags?

Regarding the Character picture exercise located at the end the following page:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter4/

> Say you have a list of lists where each value in the inner lists is a
> one-character string, like this:
>
> ```
> grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
>         ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
>         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
>         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
>         ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
>         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
>         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
>         ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
>         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
> ```
>
> You can think of `grid[x][y]` as being the character at the x- and
> y-coordinates of a “picture” drawn with text characters. The `(0, 0)`
> origin will be in the upper-left corner, the x-coordinates increase
> going right, and the y-coordinates increase going down.
>
> Copy the previous grid value, and write code that uses it to print the
> image.
>
> ```
> ..OO.OO..
> .OOOOOOO.
> .OOOOOOO.
> ..OOOOO..
> ...OOO...
> ....O....
> ```

It's different in that it doesn't hard-code the length of the list.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

x = 0
y = 0

for y in range(len(grid[x])):
    for x in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[x][y],end='')
    print()
```

Thanks for the help and let me know if this is not appropriate to post!

Answer (score 3):

It's wasteful to use `range()` and then only use the result for indexing.

Instead, just iterate directly over the values:

```
for col in range(len(grid[0])):
    for row in grid:
        print(row[col],end='')
    print()
```

We can simplify, though - use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to transpose the array:

```
transposed = zip(*grid)

for row in transposed:
    for col in row:
        print(col,end='')
    print()
```

The next simplification is instead of printing one character at a time, we can use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to form strings for printing:

```
for row in zip(*grid):
    print(''.join(row))
```

And we can join all the rows using `'\n'.join()`, giving this final version:

```
print('\n'.join(''.join(x) for x in zip(*grid)))
```

Equivalently, using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
print('\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*grid))))
```

Comment: This is great, thanks @toby. 

Can I ask why using range here is wasteful? the idea was to build a code that can work with any number of rows/columns.

I got to learn a lot here, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps "wasteful" isn't exactly the right word.  My point is that we don't need to count the columns and create indexes when it's simpler to iterate the columns directly.