# Day 3: Binary Diagnostic, part 1 (Advent of Code 2021)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Some notes that I thought would be worth mentioning up front:

- Advent of Code randomizes the input for each user, with the input format being 1,000 12-digit binary numbers delimited by newlines.
- I've verified that my solution works by submitting the generated answer on the website.

Here is the important part of the problem statement, transcribed from [Day 3 - Advent of Code 2021](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/3):

> You need to use the binary numbers in the diagnostic report to generate two new binary numbers (called the **gamma rate** and the **epsilon rate**). The power consumption can then be found by multiplying the gamma rate by the epsilon rate.
>
> Each bit in the gamma rate can be determined by finding the **most common bit in the corresponding position** of all numbers in the diagnostic report. For example, given the following diagnostic report:
>
> ```
> 00100
> 11110
> 10110
> 10111
> 10101
> 01111
> 00111
> 11100
> 10000
> 11001
> 00010
> 01010
> ```
>
> Considering only the first bit of each number, there are five `0` bits and seven `1` bits. Since the most common bit is `1`, the first bit of the gamma rate is `1`.
>
> The most common second bit of the numbers in the diagnostic report is `0`, so the second bit of the gamma rate is `0`.
>
> The most common value of the third, fourth, and fifth bits are `1`, `1`, and `0`, respectively, and so the final three bits of the gamma rate are `110`.
>
> So, the gamma rate is the binary number `10110`, or **`22`** in decimal.
>
> The epsilon rate is calculated in a similar way; rather than use the most common bit, the least common bit from each position is used. So, the epsilon rate is `01001`, or **`9`** in decimal. Multiplying the gamma rate (`22`) by the epsilon rate (`9`) produces the power consumption, **`198`**.
>
> Use the binary numbers in your diagnostic report to calculate the gamma rate and epsilon rate, then multiply them together. **What is the power consumption of the submarine?** (Be sure to represent your answer in decimal, not binary.)

#### My solution

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path


def load_numbers(input_path: Path) -> list[int]:
    with input_path.open() as f:
        return [
            int(binary_string, 2)
            for line in f
            if (binary_string := line.strip())
        ]


def binary_diagnostic_part_one(input_path: Path) -> int:
    NUM_BINARY_DIGITS = 12
    zero_counts = [0] * NUM_BINARY_DIGITS

    # used to flip all bits in gamma rate to get epsilon rate
    BIT_MASK = 2 ** NUM_BINARY_DIGITS - 1  # 0b1111_1111_1111

    numbers = load_numbers(input_path)

    for number in numbers:
        for i in range(NUM_BINARY_DIGITS):
            binary_digit = (number >> i) & 1
            zero_counts[i] += int(binary_digit == 0)

    # calculate gamma rate from zero counts
    # starting from MSB -> LSB
    n = len(numbers)
    gamma_rate = 0
    for num_zeros in reversed(zero_counts):
        gamma_digit = 0 if num_zeros > n - num_zeros else 1
        gamma_rate = (gamma_rate << 1) | gamma_digit

    epsilon_rate: int = gamma_rate ^ BIT_MASK

    return gamma_rate * epsilon_rate


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(binary_diagnostic_part_one(Path("input.txt")))
```

#### Sample input.txt

A pared-down version of the actual input.txt, for brevity.

```
010110011101
101100111000
100100000011
111000010001
001100010011
010000111100
001000100011
001000100111
010001111110
111101001011
011000101011
```

#### Output

```
3987500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddling with bits is almost *never fun*. The crux of the problem is performing a [matrix transposition](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/222293) on the bits. Performing this operation on Iterables is simplest as we can just use `zip(*binary_string)`.

```py
import io
from typing import IO


def binary_diagnostic_part_one(data: IO[str]) -> int:
    zero_counts = []
    n = 0
    with data:
        for bits in zip(*data):
            n = len(bits)
            zero_counts.append(sum(
                bit == "0"
                for bit in bits
            ))

    # calculate gamma rate from zero counts
    # starting from MSB -> LSB
    NUM_BINARY_DIGITS = 12
    BIT_MASK = 2 ** NUM_BINARY_DIGITS - 1  # 0b1111_1111_1111
    gamma_rate = 0
    for num_zeros in zero_counts:
        gamma_digit = 0 if num_zeros > n - num_zeros else 1
        gamma_rate = (gamma_rate << 1) | gamma_digit

    epsilon_rate: int = gamma_rate ^ BIT_MASK
    return gamma_rate * epsilon_rate


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # print(binary_diagnostic_part_one(Path("input.txt").open()))
    print(binary_diagnostic_part_one(io.StringIO(
        "010110011101\n"
        "101100111000\n"
        "100100000011\n"
        "111000010001\n"
        "001100010011\n"
        "010000111100\n"
        "001000100011\n"
        "001000100111\n"
        "010001111110\n"
        "111101001011\n"
        "011000101011"
    )))
```

From here it should be fairly clear we can easily merge the second for loop into the first.

```py
import io
from typing import IO


def binary_diagnostic_part_one(data: IO[str]) -> int:
    gamma = 0
    num_bits = 0
    with data:
        for num_bits, bits in enumerate(zip(*data), 1):
            zeros = sum(
                bit == "0"
                for bit in bits
            )
            gamma_digit = 0 if 2 * zeros > len(bits) else 1
            gamma = (gamma << 1) | gamma_digit

    bit_mask = 2 ** num_bits - 1
    epsilon = gamma ^ bit_mask
    return gamma * epsilon


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # print(binary_diagnostic_part_one(Path("input.txt").open()))
    print(binary_diagnostic_part_one(io.StringIO(
        "010110011101\n"
        "101100111000\n"
        "100100000011\n"
        "111000010001\n"
        "001100010011\n"
        "010000111100\n"
        "001000100011\n"
        "001000100111\n"
        "010001111110\n"
        "111101001011\n"
        "011000101011"
    )))
```

---

- Advice from [Kelly Bundy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/219610/kelly-bundy);

  > `bits` is a tuple, so no need to reinvent `zeros = bits.count("0")`.
- The code also doesn't work if the file ends in a newline. So we need to introduce the `if line.strip()` stuff.

```py
import io
from typing import IO


def binary_diagnostic_part_one(data: IO[str]) -> int:
    gamma = 0
    num_bits = 0
    with data:
        lines = (
            _line
            for line in f
            if (_line := line.strip())
        )
        for num_bits, bits in enumerate(zip(*lines), 1):
            zeros = bits.count("0")
            gamma_digit = 0 if 2 * zeros > len(bits) else 1
            gamma = (gamma << 1) | gamma_digit

    bit_mask = 2 ** num_bits - 1
    epsilon = gamma ^ bit_mask
    return gamma * epsilon


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # print(binary_diagnostic_part_one(Path("input.txt").open()))
    print(binary_diagnostic_part_one(io.StringIO(
        "010110011101\n"
        "101100111000\n"
        "100100000011\n"
        "111000010001\n"
        "001100010011\n"
        "010000111100\n"
        "001000100011\n"
        "001000100111\n"
        "010001111110\n"
        "111101001011\n"
        "011000101011\n"
    )))
```

Comment: This is much cleaner, I never thought to use matrix transpose. I like this a lot better than having to do the song & dance of bit shifts and masks for counting 0s.